# Data contract or fake data from service

Tags: angular

Hi I was given data contract as

```
{
  "swadUnsubmittedCount": 310,
  "swadSubmittedCount": 710,
  "swHwTemplateUnsubmittedCount": 200,
  "swHwTemplateSubmittedCount": 300
}
```

how to use above data contract in my ts file. I have created a object and declared above  values in that is it correct way.

```
    getChartData() {
    const newpiechart = {
      sUnsubmittedCount : " ",
      sSubmittedCount : " ",
      swHwtemplateunsubmittedCount:" ",
      swHwtemplatesubmittedCount : " ",
     }
   }

  getChartData() {
const userName = this.userService.getUserName();
const defaultRole: any = this.userService.getDefaultUserRole();
let defaultRoleId;
if (defaultRole) {
  defaultRoleId = defaultRole.roleId;
}
const swadPieChartDataURL = WebServiceUrl.dashboard.getPiechartData + '/' + defaultRoleId;
this.apiService.get(swadPieChartDataURL)
  .pipe(map(data => data))
  .subscribe(
    success => {
      this.processGetChart(success);
      console.log('success',success);
    },
    error => {
      this.showNoDataMessage = true;
      this.errors = error;
      console.log('API Error: ', this.errors);
    });
```

}

Comment: From where you are getting `data` with values? Also you have made your object as `const` you can't assign values to it that way.

Comment: No the data is mere assumption thats it at present I have given manual data

Comment: You want to assign `json` values to `newpiechart` ?

Comment: yes, How can i assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this?

```
var newpiechart: {
      sUnsubmittedCount: number,
      sSubmittedCount: number,
      swHwtemplateunsubmittedCount: number,
      swHwtemplatesubmittedCount: number
    };
```

Your `data` contains integer values so type is taken as `number`

```
const data = {
      "swadUnsubmittedCount": 310,
      "swadSubmittedCount": 710,
      "swHwTemplateUnsubmittedCount": 200,
      "swHwTemplateSubmittedCount": 300
    };
```

Assigning data values to `newpiechart`

```
newpiechart = {
      sUnsubmittedCount: data.swadUnsubmittedCount,
      sSubmittedCount: data.swadSubmittedCount,
      swHwtemplateunsubmittedCount: data.swadUnsubmittedCount,
      swHwtemplatesubmittedCount: data.swHwTemplateSubmittedCount
    };
```

Comment: See I have updated question with my ts file code.
in previous http call i used to get only two columns now they habe changes it to 4 columns but the service is not yet ready.
So i need to add the data manually and work on it.